# Book-recommendation: Biochemistry

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology

I need to have a book which covers following topics two may also be fine:

(a) Structure and role of carbohydrates, fats, fatty acids and cholesterol, proteins and amino-acids, nucleic acids. Bioenergetics.

b) Glycolysis and the Krebs cycle, oxidation and reduction, oxidative phosphorylation, energy conservation and release, ATP cycle, cyclic AMP – its structure and role.

(c) Hormone classification (steroid and peptide hormones), biosynthesis and functions.

(d) Enzymes: types and mechanisms of action.

(e) Vitamins and co-enzymes

(f) Immunoglobulin and immunity.

Comment: I would say that the "usual suspects" aka Lehninger, Stryer and Voet should all be fine. Go into a bookstore, have a look in all three of them and then decide. They are a bit different in their approach.

Comment: http://www.typotex.hu/konyv/sarkadi_livia_biokemia_mernok_szemmel But it is in Hungarian... :D You don't necessary find all of these terms in one book, because hormones, vitamins, immunoglobulins are related to human physiology, immunology, etc...

Comment: Sorry but I don't know Hungarian, but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry by Nelson and Cox is quite popular and covers everything you listed in great detail except for immunology.

I don't really have a recommendation for an immunology book; I think pretty well any of them will cover immunoglobulins (they're pretty integral). My university uses Kuby Immunology by Kindt et al. Molecular Biology of the Cell by Alberts et al. has a couple chapters (some 115 pages) on the subject. As a bonus, it's an amazing reference for cell biology (which you'll need, at least someday, if you're pursuing biochemistry).

Comment: Does the book Molecular Biology of the Cell also covers topics like:
1-Structure and function of cell and its organelles (nucleus, plasma membrane, mitochondria, Golgi bodies, endoplasmic reticulum, ribosomes, and lysosomes), cell division (mitosis and meiosis), mitotic spindle and mitotic apparatus, chromosome movements, chromosome type polytene and lambrush, organization of chromatin, heterochromatin, Cell cycle regulation.
2-Nucleic acid topology, DNA motif, DNA replication, transcription, RNA processing, translation, protein foldings and transport

Comment: @Ankit Yes, it does.